# jquery file upload list uploaded files in subfolders

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am using  blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload to upload files for each user in my site.

Everything is working fine, what I need iis to list the files I have uploaded to the server, but the files are saved in subfolders

```
files/user1
files/user2
files/user3
....
```

in this moment is just listing the files saved in files/

How can I send a parameter to UploadHandler.php to list the files in each subfolder like this

```
....jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plusui.php?id_client=user1
```

to get the value

```
/files/'.$_GET['id_client'].'/'
```

thanks.